# cpufrequency on Debian 8 (Jessie)

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit, debian-jessie, cpu-architecture

I'm running a database benchmark (TPC-H) and because of this, I need my processor not to have variable-speed. I know there are modes:

```
Powersave
Conservative
Ondemand
Usespace
Performance
```

On S.O. Red Hat, the command to freeze the frequency would be:

sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor performance

But in S.O. Debian 8 (Jessie), do you have any way to do this natively ? Best Regards Neto

Comment: What about performance mode in the BIOS. On the server HW it usualy disables lower P states.

Comment: I'm using a server HP MODEL: Proliant ML110-G9 Processador: (1) Intel Xeon E5-1603v3 (2.8GHz/4-core/10MB/140W)
In this processor is possible make set cpu mode performance on BIOS ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with BL460/DL380 types, however I believe it's the same for the ML line.

There is manual for your UEFI(BIOS):

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c04398276

The Power profile is described on the page 65. Set the 'Maximum Performance' profile.

Comment: OK, but If I set the frequency mode through the BIOS, it needs to be done by the OS as well. I use Debian 8 (Jessie).

Answer (score 0):

In Debian Jessie:

`apt install cpufrequtils`

source: [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/CpuFrequencyScaling)